# How to extend video over entire Joomla page

Tags: css, html, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla 2.5 website and I'm trying to put an html5 video on a page. The image below shows the situation. I want the video player to occupy pretty much the whole page. Using the Joomla extension, Advanced Module Manager which is installed on the site, I've checked out the Module Manager data but I can't see how to free up the area (position 7) on the left enclosed in the red rectangle in the image. I'm not even sure that this is the right way to go.

http://staging2.english2theworld.com/templates/beez_20/images/access_pos7.png

Any help would be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: Unused module positions should generally collapse. It might depend on what template you are using. It would probably help if you could provide a link to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this solution, using jQuery to change the css on the nav tag.

```
  if (window.location.pathname === "/index.php/sg-video-1" ||
      ...
      window.location.pathname === "/index.php/sg-video-8" ||
     ...
      window.location.pathname === "/index.php/toeic/toeic-practice-test/toeic-reading/toeic-end")
  {
     jQuery("div#nav").css("flex-basis","0");
   }
```

I don't for one moment think that this is the best way to go. Any suggestions are welcome.